# Oversized XML attack in axis 1.4

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention, xml

How can we prevent [oversized XML attack](http://www.ws-attacks.org/index.php/Oversized_XML_attack) in webservice implemented with Apache Axis 1.4?

Comment: Based on [this downloads page](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/releases.html), is it fair to assume that you're using a framework from 2006?

Comment: Yes, the framework is too old and there are lesser chances of upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a servlet filter which would check the size of input as well as parse through the input to block any other type of XML attack.